# Use Jquery UI AUto Complete With Asp.Net TextBox

Tags: asp.net, jquery, user-interface

Is It possible To Use ASP.NET  TextBox With Jquery UI Auto CompletE?
    I am Able to use html input control with this plugin.
    is there any sample exist?
    thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. [`asp:TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) is rendered as an input just as you use it now.

See this article: [TextBox AutoComplete with ASP.NET and jQuery UI](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515)

Here's a quick example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAuto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[id$=tbAuto]").autocomplete({ /* .. */ });
</script>
```

I've modified this example so you can see how the selector will work with [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) left as the default [`AutoID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx), but if you set it to `Static` you can use a direct selector:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAuto" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tbAuto").autocomplete({ /* .. */ });
</script>
```

Comment: How can i search in static datasource for example Generic List Or Dataset? Thanks.

Comment: That's a separate question to the one you've asked here. Post it as a new question so you will get more relevant answers.